# Right click to show popover SwiftUI / MacOS

Tags: swiftui, nsview, mac-catalyst

When I pass a binding into the NSViewRepresentable, it does not update. Any tips? My use case is to show a popover on right click.

(Also posted on Apple Dev Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655056

**Some View Struct**

```swift
@State var showMenu = false
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
          RightClickableSwiftUIView(onClick: $showMenu)
          Image(name)
             .popover(isPresented: $showMenu, ...)
    }
}
```

**RightClick.swift**

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RightClickableSwiftUIView: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var onClick: Bool

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: RightClickableView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<RightClickableSwiftUIView>) {
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> RightClickableView {
        RightClickableView(onClick: $onClick)
    }


    class RightClickableView : NSView {
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }

        init(onClick: Binding<Bool>) {
            _onClick = onClick
            super.init(frame: NSRect())
        }


        @Binding var onClick: Bool

        override func mouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
            print("left mouse")
        }

        override func rightMouseDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
            onClick = true
            print("right mouse")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh egads that's embarrassing. The class was in the struct, so of course the Binding didn't update.